# How do I count the number of rows and columns in a file using bash?

Tags: bash, row

Say I have a large file with many rows and many columns. I'd like to find out how many rows and columns I have using bash.

Comment: give an example of the input and expected output

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very familiar with bash. In R, it would look something like dim(input), which would return two numbers, #rows and #cols.

Comment: an actual input file might look like: "blah\tdata\tdata\tdata\tdata\nblah2\tdata\tdata\tdata\tdata\n"

Comment: I was hoping there might be an elegant way to do this with some built-in function...perhaps something like wc?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Columns: `awk '{print NF}' file | sort -nu | tail -n 1`

Use `head -n 1` for lowest column count, `tail -n 1` for highest column count.

Rows: `cat file | wc -l` or `wc -l < file` for the [UUOC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat) crowd.

Comment: @Tim: Typo, should be `<` obviously. This isn't how I'd do it, but it satisfies the UUOC crowd (`cat` enhances readability IMO, and I prefer it over the less readable pipes *especially* when answering newbie questions)

Comment: @Erik  You can also do "< file wc -l" and put the redirection before the command for enhanced readability.  (Although, in this case I'm not sure why you don't just do "wc -l file")

Comment: No need for the sort or the tail, just do it all in awk: awk '{if( NF > max ) max = NF} END {print max}'

Comment: How to specify a delimiter here, for example if the file is tab separated

Comment: @WilliamPursell in case you're still wondering this 8 years down the track, when using a pipe or stdin `wc` won't show a filename while `wc -l file` does.

Comment: @Joy: `awk -F'\t' '{print NF}' file | sort -nu | tail -n 1` to use tab as delimiter

Comment: This is very wasteful for long files. You can just pipe head or tail into awk like this:
`head -n 1 FILE |  awk '{print NF}'`

Comment: @CorneliusRoemer Your approach assumes all rows have the same column count. The question indicates rows have differing column counts.

Comment: I don't see where the question specifies that column counts vary by row. But sure, your solution is more general, but also slower.

Comment: Be aware that this approach is potentially flawed. The number of carriage returns in a CSV file is not always the same as the number of items, since carriage returns can be escaped and part of the data itself. The best solution to get a completely reliable answer probably involves either a scripting language like Python or Javascript or a regex or shell command of some sort more complex than what is pasted here

Answer (score 17):

Alternatively to count columns, count the separators between columns. I find this to be a good balance of brevity and ease to remember. Of course, this won't work if your data include the column separator.

```
head -n1 myfile.txt | grep -o " " | wc -l
```

Uses `head -n1` to grab the first line of the file.
Uses `grep -o` to to count all the spaces, and output each space found on a new line. Uses `wc -l` to count the number of lines.

EDIT: As Gaurav Tuli points out below, I forgot to mention you have to  mentally add 1 to the result, or otherwise script this math.

Comment: column count in a CSV will be `head -n1 myfile.txt | grep -o "," | wc -l` + 1 
because grep is counting the number of commas (or any other column separator) but the number of columns would be 1 more than that.

Answer (score 12):

If your file is big but you are certain that the number of columns remains the same for each row (and you have no heading) use:

```
head -n 1 FILE | awk '{print NF}'
```

to find the number of columns, where FILE is your file name.

To find the number of lines 'wc -l FILE' will work.

Comment: Or just `awk '{print NF; exit}'`.

Answer (score 9):

Little twist to kirill_igum's answer, and you can easily count the number of columns of any certain row you want, which was why I've come to this question, even though the question is asking for the whole file. (Though if your file has same columns in each line this also still works of course):

```
head -2 file |tail -1 |tr '\t' '\n' |wc -l
```

Gives the number of columns of row 2.
Replace 2 with 55 for example to get it for row 55.

```
-bash-4.2$ cat file
1       2       3
1       2       3       4
1       2
1       2       3       4       5

-bash-4.2$ head -1 file |tail -1 |tr '\t' '\n' |wc -l
3
-bash-4.2$ head -4 file |tail -1 |tr '\t' '\n' |wc -l
5
```

Code above works if your file is separated by tabs, as we define it to "tr". If your file has another separator, say commas, you can still count your "columns" using the same trick by simply changing the separator character "t" to ",":

```
-bash-4.2$ cat csvfile
1,2,3,4
1,2
1,2,3,4,5
-bash-4.2$ head -2 csvfile |tail -1 |tr '\,' '\n' |wc -l
2
```

Answer (score 6):

For rows you can simply use `wc -l file`

`-l` stands for total line

for columns uou can simply use `head -1 file | tr ";" "\n" | wc -l`

**Explanation**
`head -1 file`
Grabbing the first line of your file, which should be the headers,
and sending to it to the next cmd through the pipe
`| tr ";" "\n"`

`tr` stands for translate.
It will translate all `;` characters into a newline character.
In this example `;` is your delimiter.

Then it sends data to next command.

`wc -l`
Counts the total number of lines.

Answer (score 3):

You can use bash. Note for very large files in terms of GB, use `awk/wc`. However it should still be manageable in performance for files with a few MB.

```
declare -i count=0
while read
do
    ((count++))
done < file    
echo "line count: $count"
```

Answer (score 3):

If counting number of columns in the first is enough, try the following:

`awk -F'\t' '{print NF; exit}' myBigFile.tsv`

where `\t` is column delimiter.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}END{print "COLUMN NO: "NF " ROWS NO: "NR}' file
```

You can use any delimiter as field separator and can find numbers of ROWS and columns

Comment: how to is it possible to put this as an ```alias```? I tried different ways but it gives errors. Possibly related to the ```'  "```.

Answer (score 2):

Simple row count is `$(wc -l "$file")`.  Use `$(wc -lL "$file")` to show both the number of lines and the number of characters in the longest line.

Comment: True.  Silly of me to assume this was obvious: `wc -l file |cut -f 1`.

Comment: @Tim Sylvester: You know UUOC is about the wasted process, right? I'm tempted to pass it back to you for that `cut` ;)

Comment: How is it wasted if you want the file name removed from the output?  Is there a way I don't know of to make `wc` not print the filename?

Comment: Ah, using stdin doesn't show a filename.  <headsmack>  Now I feel dumb.

Answer (score 2):

```
head -1 file.tsv |head -1 train.tsv |tr '\t' '\n' |wc -l
```

take the first line, change tabs (or you can use ',' instead of '\t' for commas), count the number of lines.

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution:

`perl -ane '$maxc = $#F if $#F > $maxc; END{$maxc++; print "max columns: $maxc\nrows: $.\n"}' file`

If your input file is comma-separated:

`perl -F, -ane '$maxc = $#F if $#F > $maxc; END{$maxc++; print "max columns: $maxc\nrows: $.\n"}' file`

output:

```
max columns: 5
rows: 2
```

`-a` autosplits input line to `@F` array
`$#F` is the number of columns -1
`-F,` field separator of , instead of whitespace
`$.` is the line number (number of rows)

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way to count the columns of the first line in pure bash (no awk, perl, or other languages):

```
read -r line < $input_file
ncols=`echo $line | wc -w`
```

This will work if your data are formatted appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Following code  will do  the  job  and  will allow  you to specify field delimiter.  This is  especially useful for files containing  more than 20k lines.

```
awk 'BEGIN { 
  FS="|"; 
  min=10000; 
}
{ 
  if( NF > max ) max = NF; 
  if( NF < min ) min = NF;
} 
END { 
  print "Max=" max; 
  print "Min=" min; 
} ' myPipeDelimitedFile.dat
```