# Count number of rows in a text file using linux

Tags: linux, row

I want to know how to get the number of rows in a text file using Linux. I have tried "wc " and "wc -l ", but both display only the number of lines (columns) not the rows. Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by rows and columns in a text file?  Are you talking about a delimited file?

Comment: Thanks! No, I mean how I can know the dimension of a text file. The file has numbers with one space between them: 

Example:

1 5 2 9 3

2 8 9 6 3

4 8 5 8 3

So, I want to know the number of rows of that file (in this example is 3)

Comment: I think you are confusing lines, columns and rows. Lines and rows are the same, that is horizontal lines. Columns are the vertical ones. What do you want exactly? Provide an example with multiple lines and columns and what is your desired output.

Comment: Thanks! Just to make it simple: I want to know the dimensions of a text file using Linux. i.e. number of rows and number of columns.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I count the number of rows and columns in a file using bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761212/how-do-i-count-the-number-of-rows-and-columns-in-a-file-using-bash)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`wc -l < <filename>` displays lines for me

example file with numbers 1 - 7

outputs:

```
scottsmudger@ns207588:~ $wc -l < test
7
```

From the man page:

```
-l, --lines
    print the newline counts
```

Comment: Thanks! This returns the number of columns but not the number of rows?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the number of fields in each line you can use awk :

- awk reads a line from the file and puts it into an internal variable called $0 .
  Each line is called record. By default, every line is terminated by a newline.
- Then, every record or line is divided into separate words or fields. Every
  word is stored in numbered variables $1 , $2 , and so on. There can be as
  many as 100 fields per record.
- awk has an internal variable called IFS (Internal Field Separator). IFS is
  normally whitespace.

In this case we can use an internal built-in
variable called NF, which will keep track of field numbers. Typically, the maximum
field number will be 100.

```
awk '{  print NF }' file_name
```

this command will print the number of columns in each line